# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Controller when using an ActiveRecord with a table name and a postgresql view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have an Event which belongs to Repeat and I am trying to display the repeat title when displaying an event. But I do not want two database calls which this would make

```
@event.Repeat.title
```

I created a postgresql view using a migration below

```
class EventWithRepeat < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    self.connection.execute %Q( create view event_with_repeat as
                                Select events.*, repeats.title as RepeatTitle from Events
                                inner join repeats on events.repeat_id = repeats.id; )
  end

  def down
    self.connection.execute %Q( drop view event_with_repeat; )
  end

end
```

**The issue is definitely with the migration above. I cannot seem to run just that migration. Executing rake db:migrate does not do anything. rake db:migrate:down with the version results in an error because the relation does not exists so it cannot drop it.**

Creating the SQL view directly in the database does work but my migration does not seem to execute. I am using rails 5.

This is my ActiveRecord class

```
class EventRepeat < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "event_with_repeat"
  self.primary_key = "id"

  def readonly?
    true
  end
end
```

This is the method in my controller class

```
def show
    @event = EventRepeat.find(params[:id])
end
```

I ran the migrations and I can the view in psql so the view is present. I did do db:reset but the did not help.

The error message shows that the issue is with this SQL

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                     c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                FROM pg_attribute a
                LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
                LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"event_with_repeat"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

and the error message is

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "event_with_repeat" does not exist
```

but the view event_with_repeat does exist.

I have this in my view

```
<%= @event.RepeatTitle %>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error and what was wrong with the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by deleting the migration and creating it again. But, I run into the same issue again if I execute rake db:reset. This command creates the tables but not the postgresql view and it doesn't look like it is executing the last migration. I have to delete the migration and create it again to get it working.

It looks like this migration is only run once?

The order of in which the migrations were created

1. 20170515163011_create_events
2. 20170520203458_create_repeats
3. 20170520203852_add_repeat_to_event
4. 20170521190734_event_with_repeat

I change the schema format to :sql config.active_record.schema_format :sql in application.rb

Dumping the schema to structure.sql does work but running rake db:reset again does not create the view. I always have to delete the migration and create it again.